# This page isn’t working examlpe.in is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After uploading theme and downloading prestashop when i open my home page it's giving me this error "This page isn’t working example.in is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"[image]

Comment: I'd suggest editing the /config/defines.inc.php file and setting _PS_MODE_DEV_ to 'true', so you could see what is the PHP error causing this 500 HTTP error.

Comment: Brother this(define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);) is already set as true.

Comment: Perfect. If nothing showed up, then alternately, you can make sure that log_errors is set to ‘On’ in your php.ini and then check your PHP error log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same problem and i write to prestashop support and they gave me following solution and it worked

`Memory limit: 512M 
 Max execution time: 300 
 Upload Max File size: 64M`

You can change this in your WHM or php.ini file.